# Soql taking too long - log says 15 seconds

Tags: soql, performance

We are getting UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW error couple time a week. This time I was able to get the logs of it by setting user trace flag on production. When I check the logs, I see that a single SOQL query took 15 seconds.

[image]

[image]

When I check successful transactions, I can see this specific query takes around 400-500ms (still much longer than others but not this magnitude).

The question is, what might be the reason for a single query to take this long?

Also, to solve this particular problem, my initial thought was caching the query results but since I don't know *what* causes it, not sure if caching would be the solution.

Comment: Normal behaviour if you have at least one other query with FOR UPDATE that gets the same record(s) and is long running... other queries get blocked IIRC, with normally a 10 second timeout to QueryException

Comment: I looked up and found out there are 5 usages of FOR UPDATE. They are not related to this contact or the contact trigger directly. Removed those just in case and will check future logs. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I said 'directly' because we send this contact record and a custom object record that has a that contact as a look-up in the same,single composite request [first action is post/contact, second action is post/costomRecord]. FOR UPDATEs were related to that object. Not sure if this info is useful at all but writing just in case I am missing something about composite requests.

Comment: Row locking cascades through master detail, but IIRC also SetNull lookups. Check what you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely this is due to locking through related objects causing queuing of, then timeout for, a subset of your concurrent queries (or DML).

As per the [documentation](https://d259t2jj6zp7qm.cloudfront.net/images/20210727114613/SF_Record-Locking-Cheatsheet_web-1.pdf), when SOQL is used with FOR UPDATE, all those records get locked:

| Operation | Locks | Detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SELECT FOR UPDATE SOQL query | Selected records | Locks all records retrieved in SELECT statement that uses FOR UPDATE |

I read this as locking both the top-level records and any related records retrieved.

When it comes to record manipulation where the record has Lookup fields, locks are automatically applied thus (regardless as to whether FOR UPDATE was used or not):

| Operation | Locks | Detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Insert new or update record with lookup value | Lookup record | Locks only occur if lookup relationship is not configured to clear the value of this field if the lookup record is deleted |

It is highly likely that your over-all solution happens to touch on one or other of these scenarios (and perhaps others described in the above "cheatsheet"). If you then have a lot of transactions that get blocked on a record lock, or a smaller number of longer running transactions getting blocked on a record lock, there can be a cumulative delay effect on those transactions later in the queue of blocked transactions and this could result in such long processing delays (in excess of 10 CPU seconds) that the blocked transaction is unblocked with a `QueryException` (or `DmlException`) as covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_for_update.htm).

Note that locks are released only once the locking transaction has completed.

Comment: Even after deleting FOR UPDATEs I saw 12 and 19 seconds of query timing on different transactions. I am out of researchable areas so I will just give up on the 'understanding' part and will cache the query result and run it daily via batch or something. Thank you for your time, comments and answer.

Comment: You don't even need FOR UPDATE for locking to happen - see second table above.